# jmock oneOf not called

Tags: java, jmock

I have a class under test with jmock and I was making a change to it and expecting it to fail but it didn't. Before my change I had a alert() method that was getting called as expected and the test was passing. After I made the change my alert() method should no longer get called, however the unit test continued working! I checked it by putting a breakpoint and stepping through and it in fact does NOT call alert(), however jmock seems to think it does. Any ideas on how to figure out what's going on here?

```
Mockery context = new Mockery();
final NotifierInterface notifier = context.mock(NotifierInterface.class);

context.checking(new Expectations() {{
  oneOf(notifier).alert(with(any(String.class)));
  ...
}

analyzer = new Analyzer(notifier);
analyzer.run();
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with jMock, but the [documentation](http://jmock.org/getting-started.html) implies you need to call `context.assertIsSatisfied()` in order to verify the expectations. Are you calling this further along in your code? If not, your test will probably always pass.

Comment: Ah nice catch, that was it indeed!

Comment: You can annotate the test class with @RunWith(JMock.class), this will invoke context.assertIsSatisfied() for you automatically. @andersschuller